# Most Common Difference Between Two Consecutive Primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The question is as stated in the title. I was given this interesting problem by a friend of mine, but I don't know how to proceed with a solution. The immediate thought I had was that the most common difference is 2 since all primes are odd (except 2), but that seems trivial and silly. Any thoughts/hints/suggestions on how to find the most common difference? I suspect it has something to do with modular arithmetic but I'm not too sure.

Any and all help is appreciated :)

Thanks for reading,

A

Edit: To specify the term "most common," I mean to ask what is the most abundant or frequently occurring difference between two consecutive primes.

Comment: Most common in what sense? Do you mean the average gap between primes?

Comment: Most common as in the most occurring. I've made an edit to clarify.

Comment: Read this article http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap

Comment: Thanks marwalix! I didn't know about this subject. This gives me a good place to start.

Comment: Most occurring is not normally a useful notion when there are infinitely many elements in the list. As far as I know, it is not even known whether a positive proportion of prime gaps are bounded.

Comment: It would be extremely counterintuitive if the gaps between primes reached some upper bound.

Comment: @JonathanHebert What do you mean? they clearly never reach an upper bound, since they can be arbitrarily large: consider $n!+2,n!+3,\ldots,n!+n, n\ge 2$, none of which is prime and so the prime gap there (between the largest prime less than $n!+2$ and least prime larger than $n!+n$) is $\ge n$.

Answer (score 2):

From the PNT, the average prime gap around $n$ is $\sim\log n$, therefore the quantity you're interested in can't be bounded above. You can also take a glance on Marek Wolf's work about "jumping champions", which correspond to the most frequent prime gaps in a finite range, and which are conjectured to be the primorials, $2, 6, 30, 210...$. It is indeed related to modular arithmetic, since those numbers are in some sense "like $0$" as far as distance between primes is concerned. See also my question untitled "About Goldbach's conjecture" on Mathoverflow, or my blog ideasfornumbertheory.com for further insights, though expressed in an unrigorous fashion.

Comment: I took a look at the very interesting article "Jumping Champions." So is the most common gap between successive primes just the largest primorial in that finite range?

Comment: As I wrote above, it's a conjecture, no proof exists yet (as far as I know).

Comment: So the only definite answer to "what is the most common gap between successive primes" is that it's impossible to determine?

Comment: The most reasonable answer would probably be "we don't know yet".